# Decomposing a force vector at an arbitrary angle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, vectors

[image]

I was solving an exercise about dynamics and inclined ramps and I came across the need to discover the intensity of a force in a certain direction that was neither the $x$ or $y$ axis. How do I discover how much a certain force pulls at a certain angle?

Comment: What is the "intensity" of a force?  Perhaps you should give an example of such a problem as it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are asking can you give an example or something ? describe your question and what you really wanna ask properly

Comment: I tried adding a picture, don’t  know if it will help.

Comment: So your picture  looks straightforward. What do you find hard? You need to incude the weight and  the normal force and make sure everything adds to zero.

Comment: I’ll change the picture again, the first one is confusing

Comment: I need to discover the component of F1 which pulls in the direction of the green arrow. I know how to do it for the horizontal and vertical components (multiply by the cosine and sine, respectively), but not for a 30 degree angle for example.

Answer (score 2):

You have to calculate the projection of the force vector on the direction vector (i.e. norm one) you are interested in. The projection of vector $\mathbf{v}$ on the vector $\mathbf{n}$ is the scalar product $\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{n}$.

Let's say your force vector is given by $\mathbf{F} = (F_x,F_y)^T$ and you want to calculate the part that pulls along the vector $\mathbf{p} = (p_x,p_y)^T$, with $\tan\alpha = p_y/p_x$. Then the direction vector along $\mathbf{p}$ is given by
$$\mathbf{n}_p = (\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)^T.$$
Note that $|\mathbf{n}_p|=1$, due to the parametrization with $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Then the magnitude of the force along $\mathbf{n}_p$ is given by
$$\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}_p = F_x\cos\alpha+F_y\sin\alpha.$$
You see that this simplifies to what you already know when $\mathbf{p}$ points along the x- or y-direction, since then either $\sin\alpha$ or $\cos\alpha$ is zero.

Comment: Thank you, I believe this solves the problem